# Check for 5 consecutive TRUE values from the back of a vector

Tags: r, vector, sequence

I have the following data:

```
x <- c(F, T, T, T, F, T, T, T, T, T)
names(x) <- letters[1:10]
y <- c(T, F, T, T, T, F, T, T, T, T)
names(y) <- letters[1:10]
z <- c(T, T, F, T, T, T, T, T, F, F)
names(z) <- letters[1:10]
a <- c(T, T, T, T, T, F, T, F, T, T, T, T, T)
names(a) <- letters[1:13]
```

I want to create a function which can subset the first 5 consecutive `T` values, but from the back. For example, if I pass `x` object through that function, I should get the following output:

```
#    f    g    h    i    j 
# TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Or if I pass `y` through it, I should just get an `NA`. Because there are no first 5 `T` values from the back.

`z` has first 5 consecutive `T` values in the middle and, hence, those should be returned.

```
#    d    e    f    g    h 
# TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

In `a`, there are two sets of 5 consecutive values, in the beginning and in the end. Since, the first group from the back would be the one at the end and hence those values should be returned.

```
#    i    j    k    l    m 
# TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

How can I make this function?

Comment: Starting point: `rev(x)[rev(x)][1:5]`

Comment: oops,  this comment-answer doesn't handle the *consecutive* part

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a basic for loop:

```
foo <- function(x) {
  true_in_a_row <- 0L
  found         <- FALSE
  for (i in length(x):1L) {
    if (x[i]) true_in_a_row <- true_in_a_row + 1L else true_in_a_row <- 0L
    if (true_in_a_row == 5L) {
      found <- TRUE
      break
    }
  }
  if (found) x[i:(i+4L)] else NA
}
```

---

```
foo(x)
#    f    g    h    i    j 
# TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 
foo(y)
# [1] NA
foo(z)
#    d    e    f    g    h 
# TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 
foo(a)
#    i    j    k    l    m 
# TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

---

#### Benchmark

```
set.seed(42)
x <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size = 1e6, replace = TRUE)
bench::mark(foo(x), last5(x), f_zoo(x), f_gregexpr(x), f_rle(x), f_embed(x))[1:4]
# # A tibble: 6 × 4
#   expression         min   median   `itr/sec`
#   <bch:expr>    <bch:tm> <bch:tm>       <dbl>
# 1 foo(x)           1.9µs    6.2µs 152792.    
# 2 last5(x)         107ms 149.53ms      5.35  
# 3 f_zoo(x)        14.39s   14.39s      0.0695
# 4 f_gregexpr(x) 259.58ms 283.42ms      3.53  
# 5 f_rle(x)         1.94s    1.94s      0.514 
# 6 f_embed(x)    187.22ms 201.41ms      5.04  

# With sparser TRUEs:
x <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size = 1e6, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.05, 0.95))
bench::mark(foo(x), last5(x), f_zoo(x), f_gregexpr(x), f_rle(x), f_embed(x))[1:4]
# 1 foo(x)         33.12ms  33.36ms    29.0  
# 2 last5(x)       13.11ms   25.5ms    37.9  
# 3 f_zoo(x)         5.14s    5.14s     0.194
# 4 f_gregexpr(x)  75.98ms  76.72ms    12.6  
# 5 f_rle(x)      208.37ms 221.82ms     4.58 
# 6 f_embed(x)     69.01ms  80.64ms    11.9
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution using `rle` to calculate runs of values

```
last5 <- function(x) {
  with(rle(x), {
    group <- tail(which(lengths>=5 & values), 1)
    if (length(group)<1) return(NA)
    start <- ifelse(group>1, sum(lengths[1:(group-1)]),0) + (lengths[group]-5)+1
    x[start:(start+4)]
  })  
}
```

which gives the following output

```
last5(x)
#    f    g    h    i    j 
# TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 
last5(y)
# [1] NA
last5(z)
#    d    e    f    g    h 
# TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 
last5(a)
#    i    j    k    l    m 
# TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

The idea is that it finds all runs with more than 5 TRUE values, then takes the last group (if there is one) and takes the last 5 values from that group)

Comment: "The answer is ALWAYS  rle() "   -- me.

Answer (score 4):

This is an opportunity for showcasing `stats::filter`, one of my favorite R functions. The following solution is unlikely to be significantly more efficient than the simple `for` loop (that could be easily achieved by implementing the `for` loop with Rcpp). However, the approach allows extending the problem to finding all sequences in an efficient way.

```
f_filter <- function(x) {
  x <- rev(x)
  y <- stats::filter(x, rep(1, 5), sides = 1)
  i <- which(y == 5)[1]
  if (is.finite(i)) x[i:(i-4)] else NA
}

f_filter(x)
#   f    g    h    i    j 
#TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 
f_filter(y)
#[1] NA
f_filter(z)
#   d    e    f    g    h 
#TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 
f_filter(a)
#   i    j    k    l    m 
#TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 

set.seed(42)
x <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size = 1e6, replace = TRUE)
bench::mark(foo(x), f_filter(x))[1:4]
#  expression       min   median `itr/sec`
#  <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl>
#1 foo(x)         1.9µs    2.1µs  444340. 
#2 f_filter(x)   19.1ms   19.8ms      49.9

x <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size = 1e6, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.05, 0.95))
bench::mark(foo(x), f_filter(x))[1:4]
#  expression       min   median `itr/sec`
#  <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl>
#1 foo(x)        42.6ms   43.1ms      23.1
#2 f_filter(x)   18.1ms   18.9ms      52.9
```

Comment: Really interesting application of `stats::filter`, +1!

Answer (score 3):

Actually you have many options to implement it, and below are just three of them:

1. `gregexpr`

```
f <- function(v) {
    idx <- tail(gregexpr("1{5}", paste0(+v, collapse = ""))[[1]], 1)
    if (idx <= 0) NA else v[idx + (0:4)]
}
```

2. `rle`

```
f <- function(v) {
    r <- tail(Filter(
        \(x) sum(x) == 5,
        split(v, with(rle(v), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths)))
    ), 1)
    if (length(r)) r[[1]] else NA
}
```

3. `embed`

```
f <- function(v) {
    idx <- which(rowSums(embed(v, 5)) == 5)
    if (length(idx)) v[max(idx) + (0:4)] else NA
}
```

---

## Output

```
> f(x)
   f    g    h    i    j
TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

> f(y)
[1] NA

> f(z)
   d    e    f    g    h
TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

> f(a)
   i    j    k    l    m
TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: Somehow, diving into regex to do a simple boolean inspection seems like the long way around.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft you are right, that's true that `regexp` plays a trick but far less efficient.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I added a version with `rle`

Answer (score 3):

For each subsequence of 5 check if it is all TRUE returning a logical vector and apply which to get the positions, `wx`.  If it is non-empty return the 5 elements that end in the largest entry in `wx` and other return `NA`.

```
library(zoo)

f <- function(zz) {
  wx <- which(rollapplyr(zz, 5, all, fill = FALSE))
  if (length(wx) > 0) zz[seq(to = max(wx), length = 5)] else NA
}

# tests

f(x)
##    f    g    h    i    j 
## TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 

f(y)
## [1] NA

f(z)
##    d    e    f    g    h 
## TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 

f(a)
##    i    j    k    l    m 
## TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```